# ERROR ITMS-90596 while publishing nativescript ios app

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to publish ios app via Transporter.
App (.ipa) builded by Sidekick (cloud).

I'm getting an error as below:

> ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at
>   'Payload/frontend.app/Assets.car' can't be processed. Rebuild your
>   app, and all included extensions and frameworks, with the latest GM
>   version of Xcode and resubmit."

Any help ?

For Android version all is working pretty well

Comment: Did you add any image to asset catalog? Can you post the `package.json`, to see the versions and plugins.

Comment: package.json -> https://pastebin.com/pWPcE1eN

Yes, I added a few images to src/assets/images

Comment: I meant, did you add any image to asset catalog?

Comment: Where exactly? You meant App_Resources/iOS ?
If yes then, I added there logo images (generated via Sidekick generator)

Comment: I had this problem due problems with the tools version. Tried updating to the last Xcode and working. I don't know Sidekick but it could be something similar.